# How to withdraw money from Magento Marketplace

Tags: marketplace

I sell my extensions on Magento Marketplace.

I had some sales and there are some money in my account.

How do I withdraw it?

Magento is supposed to send it to my paypal but it never does.

I wrote to them but haven't heard from them ever since.

Any of you deal with that kind of problem?

**PS**: Apparently I am not alone - this guy rants on [how terrible Magento Marketplace is to its developers](https://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/Marketplace-services-are-TERRIBLE/m-p/70596#M901).